# Bootstrap 4 theme for Wordpress - vertical align doesn't work

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm using Understrap (Bootstrap 4 + Wordpress) and none of they ways of vertical centering divs shown here in other discussions work for me.

I have this html:

```html
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">Test</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12">Test</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12">Test</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12">Test</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">Test</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And this css:

```css
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

html {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 height: 100%;
}
```

I also tried te version with edited css:

```css
.vertical-center  {
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline-block;
float: none;
}
```

(tried assigning this special class to both jumbotron and each div)
None of these solutions work and I don't really know why. It's all aligned to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `position: absolute;` method to vertically centre the element:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.vertical-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0; /*set this to 50% if you want to also  horizontally center the element */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron vertical-center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">Test</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12">Test</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12">Test</div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12">Test</div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-12">Test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```